# How to get Gutenberg pattern sync status for custom pattern listings table?

Tags: block-editor, sync

I am using classic WordPress (no FSE) but with Gutenberg. I have registered a submenu page for the post_type `wp_block` to get an admin interface for my Gutenberg patterns.

Since WP 6.3 they merged Block patterns (block templates sort of) into Resuable Blocks `post_type=wp_block` (now called Pattern). A pattern can instead be synced or not.

I would like to show/indicate if the pattern is synced on each `wp_block` post in the edit list (`/edit.php?post_type=wp_block`). Either as a separate column or as a text appended to the title.

[image: Screenshot of what I would like to do, show synced status in list view of post_type=wp_block]

I have sucessfully created a custom column with the good old:

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'setup_pattern_columns', 'wp_block');
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'fill_pattern_columns', 10, 2 );
```

I have searched both the web and my database to try to find a value attached to the post which states if it's synced or not but I cannot find where that is stored. I know that posts with a synced block reference the original pattern by putting this inside post_content `<!-- wp:block {"ref":1262} /-->` and I can use a regex function to figure that out. But it will not help me in this case though since it's the original pattern I want to lookup.

In `post_meta` I only see one row with the key `wp_pattern_sync_status` and value *unsynced* (and it's for another post). Where are the other wp_pattern_sync_status:es?

Does anyone know if/where the synced option is stored and how to retrieve it? I mean, where does the info in div `components-panel__row edit-post-sync-status` come from when editing the pattern in Gutenberg?

[image: Sync status is shown when editing a pattern in Gutenberg]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is easy: if the block does not have an 'unsynced' post meta associate with it, this means that is a synced pattern.
Look at the format of the json file of two exported patterns, a synced and a non synced and you will see the same: a non synced has this property: "syncStatus": "unsynced" and a synced one has this other property: "syncStatus": ""